# How is Phi Beta Kappa and Skull and Bones historically connected to Sigma Pi Phi fraternity also known as the Boulé?

Tags: united-states

According to the history of [Sigma Pi Phi Fraternity](https://www.sigmapiphi.org/home/) also known as [the Boulé](https://www.sigmapiphi.org/home/history-of-the-boule.php) the organization was founded in 1904 by [Henry McKee Minton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_McKee_Minton) and five other men

> [image]
>
> Sigma Pi Phi fraternity was formed in 1904 in Philadelphia,
>   Pennsylvania by a group of six African American professional men. The
>   fraternity founders included; Henry McKee Minton, Dr. Algernon B.
>   Jackson, Dr. Edwin C. Howard, Dr. Richard J. Warrick, Robert J. Abele,
>   and Eugene T. Hinson.
>
> The fraternity was established so that educated African American men,
>   who were accomplished in their professions, could have a social,
>   spiritual and communial gathering space. Within the group, members are
>   referred to as arcons and wives as archousai.
>
> The group's second member Boule "Beta Boule" was formed in 1907 in
>   Chicago followed by it's third member Boule in Baltimore in 1908. The
>   organization gradually became nationwide and has included many
>   prominent men including Martin Luther King, Jr. WEB Dubois, Arthur
>   Ashe, Ron Brown, Earl Graves of Black Enterprise Magazine, and John
>   Johnson of Ebony Magazine. Most prominent African Americans are
>   members including college presidents, congressmen, cabinet members,
>   and nationally prominent figures. The fraternity is currently
>   comprised of 112 member Boules or chapters.
>
> The fraternity is often referred to as the Boule, which in fraternity
>   parlance means "a council of noblemen".
>
> The meaning of the words Sigma Pi Phi, the titles given to its members
>   and their wives, its officers and the names of its local units are
>   derived from Greek history and tradition as well.

In *[History of Sigma Pi Phi: First of the Negro-American Greek-letter Fraternities](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$b71218;view=1up;seq=1)* by [Charles H. Wesley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Wesley) at [page *28*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$b71218;view=1up;seq=32) Wesley quotes Minton summarizing the goals of the creation of the organization:

> In summary, Minton wanted to create an organization which would
>   partake, in his own words, of "the tenets of Skull and Bones at Yale
>   and Phi Beta Kappa,"

What are the times, people, places, events and literature connecting between [Phi Beta Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_Beta_Kappa) and [Skull and Bones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skull_and_Bones) with Sigma Pi Phi Fraternity also known as the Boulé?